# I want to change path in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project. My client wants a different link format, like:

```
http://studentfintech.app/short_form
```

But, at this time, the page link is:

```
http://studentfintech.app/Money/short_form
```

If I remove the `MoneyController`, this will be removed, but this is not accessible without a controller.

Please share your ideas to access this page according to this link:

```
http://studentfintech.app/short_form
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 Rewriting URLs is already part of ASP.NET Core. But you mixed quite a few tags above that belong to the legacy ASP.NET, so are you sure what actually is the framework you are using?

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful for you:

[Routing in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://code-maze.com/routing-asp-net-core-mvc/)

You can specify a route like this:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "short_form",
    pattern: "short_form",
    defaults: new { controller = "Money", action = "short_form" });
```

Comment: Thank you!     my problem has been solved

Comment: @Munir Ahmad I'm glad of helping you, Please mark this post as answer thanks.

Comment: @MunirAhmad: Be aware that you can only have one default controller, so this won’t work if you want to shorten paths to actions in other controllers as well, such as your `HomeController`. This will also shorten the path for _all_ actions in your `MoneyController`. The alternative, if those limitations aren’t acceptable, is to either setup individual routes for each shortcut or, better yet, use URL rewriting.

Comment: @MunirAhmad: Also, to accept an answer, click the gray checkbox next to the answer, below the voting buttons. That will mark this question as resolved.